# ansible role unable to find module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a test.yml file which has a role to checkout code from git (both copied below):

**site.yml**

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  user: me
  roles: 
  - role: test-role
```

**main.yml file in test-role/tasks**

```
---

- name: fetching my repo
  vars: 
    my_repo_url: git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/my-server.git
    my_proj_path: /tmp/repos/my-server/ 
  tasks: 
   - name: check out git repository on host
     git: repo={{ my_repo_url }} dest={{ my_proj_path }} accept_hostkey=yes
```

**hosts:**

```
[webservers]
testserver ansible_ssh_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx ansible_ssh_port=xxxx
```

when I run the following:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml
```

I am getting the exception copied below referencing the main.yml file in the tasks section of the role.  Any ideas what I might have misconfigured.

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/home/user/git/roles/test-role/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: fetching my repo
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/home/user/git/test/roles/test-role/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: fetching my repo
  ^ here
```

**Update**
Tried changing as per Konstantin's feedback but I am getting more or less the same exception:

**roles/test-role/defaults/main.yml**

```
---
  vars: 
    my_repo_url: git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/my-server.git
    my_proj_path: /tmp/repos/my-server/
```

**tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: fetching my repo
  tasks: 
   - name: check out git repository on host
     git: repo={{ my_repo_url }} dest={{ my_proj_path }} accept_hostkey=yes
```

**Exception**:
Now its complaining about the line below.  I get the same response when I run syntax check.

```
---
- name: fetching my repo
  ^ here
```

**Update**
Followed Konstantin and Avalon's answers - I was able to run the task successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main.yml` for role should contain only list of tasks, nothing else.

Split your file into `test-role/defaults/main.yml` (variables):

```
---
my_repo_url: git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/my-server.git
my_proj_path: /tmp/repos/my-server/
```

and `test-role/tasks/main.yml` (tasks):

```
---
# fetching my repo
- name: check out git repository on host
  git: repo={{ my_repo_url }} dest={{ my_proj_path }} accept_hostkey=yes
```

Comment: spaciba - Updated my original post with your recommendation but its not working - any thoughts - thanks in advance

Comment: spaciba - both answers were equally useful

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Konstantin said, your tasks should only contain tasks. Variables need to be defined in a separate file. Additionally, your syntax/formatting could be improved upon.

**site.yml**

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  user: me
  roles: 
    - test-role
```

**roles/test-role/tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: fetching my repo
  git: repo={{ my_repo_url }} dest={{ my_proj_path }} accept_hostkey=yes
```

**roles/test-role/vars/main.yml**

```
---
my_repo_url: git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/my-server.git
my_proj_path: /tmp/repos/my-server/
```

Also, I recommend setting your inventory path in your ansible.cfg file. The config file can either be in /etc/ansible.cfg or in the same directory as your playbooks (I personally have mine in the same directory as my playbook).

**ansible.cfg**

```
inventory      = inventory/hosts
```

If you do this, you will not have to specify the inventory file location when you run your playbook. If nothing else, it will save you a few keystrokes.

You should review [this URL](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html) for best practices and examples for creating your roles structure.

Comment: thank you - works like a charm.  I accepted konstantin's answer since it came in first (upvoted both).